# How to locate a web element when is embeded in span/li & class

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Below is my code:

```
<div class="rightMenu">
<ul>
<!-- ngRepeat: item in tab.rightMenuList -->
<li class="dropdown ng-scope" on-toggle="toggled(open)" dropdown="" ng-repeat="item in tab.rightMenuList">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle="" ng-click="item.click()" href="" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
<!-- ngInclude: item.iconUrl -->
<span class="iconText ng-binding bvTextColor" font-color="">Cancel</span>
</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu ng-hide" ng-show="(item.dropDownMenu.length > 0)">
<!-- ngRepeat: sort in item.dropDownMenu -->
</ul>
<ul class="dropdown-menu ng-hide" ng-show="(item.replyOptions.length > 0)">
<!-- ngRepeat: option in item.replyOptions -->
</ul>
</li>
<!-- end ngRepeat: item in tab.rightMenuList -->
<li class="dropdown ng-scope" on-toggle="toggled(open)" dropdown="" ng-repeat="item in tab.rightMenuList">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle="" ng-click="item.click()" href="" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
<!-- ngInclude: item.iconUrl -->
<span class="iconText ng-binding bvTextColor" font-color="">Save</span>
</a>
```

Now i wanted to locate "Save" that is embeded in the anchor tag using selenium web driver. please help me out`enter code here`

Comment: Reformatted question text out of the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
element = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("div.rightMenu > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a > span")
print element.text
```

Try to use your chrome console window to test it before run it. Use jquery:

```
$("div.rightMenu > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a > span).text()
```

Ps. Im not sure about nth-child(2), I assume its start from 1 and not from 0. You could also try `"li:last-child"` if its last `li`